# Change the label of "none" value of a picklist

Tags: picklist, default-value, standardlayout

I had a generic question. can the "none-" value of a standard picklist be changed to something else like "default" or "select" etc. What I want here is that, I want the default value to be present, but I want to change its label to something else

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the none value being displayed for a Picklist and set a default by

1. Making the picklist mandatory on the page layouts
2. Selecting one picklist value to be the default value. If you are using Record Types this can be a different value for each one, otherwise you will
   have one default value set.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the 'none' value.

If you have recordtypes activated for that object, what you can do is add the required default value (e.g. 'default' or 'select') to the picklist values on the field definition. Then make that the default value. 
Additionally, in the recordtype section select the recordtype, then select that picklist and only select the picklist values that you need. That will hide the standard 'none' value.